# return data for specific user nodejs api

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a rest api end point (http://localhost:3000/api/skills) that retrieves a list of Skills i.e. coding, driving and etc.

- `User` is user model schema; contains `id` and `email`
- `Skill` is skill model schema; contains `name`

  ```
  export async function getList(req, res, next) {
    try {
      const promise = await Promise.all([
        User.findById(req.user._id),
        Skill.list({ skip: req.query.skip, limit: req.query.limit }),
      ]);

      const skills = promise[1].reduce((arr, skill) => {
        arr.push({
          ...skill.toJSON(),
        });

        return arr;
      }, []);

      return res.status(HTTPStatus.OK).json(skills);
    } catch (err) {
      err.status = HTTPStatus.BAD_REQUEST;
      return next(err);
    }
  }
  ```

When I make a call to this api, it returns the set of skills for all the users available in the database. i.e. if I have two users, it will return skills for both users.

How do I make it that it returns it only for that specific user I want?

Here is a [gist](https://gist.github.com/HamidHabib/62cd19703fa4f511c81696a7f122242e) for it

Comment: What's the real question here, how do you filter a Mongo query?

Comment: There is no relation between User and Skill.

Comment: @sookie so each Skill has to have like an author id or something?

Comment: Each user should have a skill_id or skills(array of skill_id), which should also be related to each skill. Skill will contain skill_id and name.

Comment: Ah got you. Let me try it! Thanks :)